# Is limit of $a.b^2$ undetermined when $a\rightarrow+\infty$, $b\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: limits

Let's consider two independent quantities depending on a variable $x$ (with an *unknown* dependence): $a(x)$ and $b(x)$.

Let's consider the limits when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ : $a\rightarrow+\infty$, and $b\rightarrow 0$. The product $a \cdot b$ is so-called undetermined.

What about $a \cdot b^2$ ? What about $a^2 \cdot b$ ? Could we a priori know it, because one has a bigger power than the other ?

So, do we have for example $a \cdot b^2\rightarrow 0$ "because" $b$ has a power $2$.

Comment: If it is unknown dependence between $a$ and $b$, then simply denote $c=b^2$ and you will have same undetermined  case $a\cdot c$, with only addition $c\geqslant 0$.

Comment: The squaring is immaterial; introduce $c = b^2$, and we're asking about $a \cdot c$.

Comment: thanks a lot guys and sorry for my stupid question. I had to be sure about this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not a stupid question. It's a sign of learning if something mysterious later seems obvious. :)

Answer (score 2):

You definitely cannot, in general, conclude anything about $ab^2$ (or indeed $ab^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N_+$).

Simplest possible counterexample: take $a(x) := x^{n+1}$ and $b(x) := \frac1x$. Now $ab^n = x$, which goes to infinity.

Comment: For another interesting example $a=e^x$ and $b=1/x$. Then $ab^n \to \infty$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$